# My SelectionSort method does not work. Why?

Tags: java, sorting, selection, linked-list

I am trying to use the selection sort algorithm in a version of the doubly linked list that I wrote myself. For this question we can assume that there are no errors elsewhere other than the code that I post (at least, none relevant to the question). I have done plenty of testing.

here is my method:

```
public void selectionSort(){

    ListItem front = head;
    ListItem current;
    T currentLowest;
    T potentialLowest;
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a<count-1; a++){
        System.out.println("a: "+a);
        currentLowest = (T) front.content;
        front = front.next;
        current = front.next;
    for(int i = a+1; i<count; i++){
        System.out.println("i: "+i);
**(29)**    potentialLowest = (T) current.content;
        if (potentialLowest.compareTo(currentLowest)==-1)
        {
            currentLowest = (T) current.content;
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
        if(current.next == null)break;

        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println("swapped"+a+","+lowestIndex);
    swap(a, lowestIndex);
}
```

}

It is sorting a list of 100 integers. Here is the last bit of output before I receive a null pointer on line 29 (marked).

swapped95,97

a: 96
i: 97
i: 98

swapped96,97

a: 97
i: 98

swapped97,97

a: 98
i: 99
(null pointer)

I had this working earlier but it was horribly optimized. After making some changes, I'm stuck with this. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might arise in the first iteration of your sorting loop. Considering the first line in this function (`ListItem front = head`) points the `front` to the first element of the list, it seems that by calling: `front = front.next; current = front.next;` you actually 'skip' the element at index 1 in the list and start your comparison loop of the element at index 2.

For example, if your (unsorted) list looks like this:

`[54, 11, 25, 34]`

It will look like

`[25, 11, 54, 34]`

after the first iteration of your sorting algorithm. Since the next iteration will start at index 1, the element 11 will never be placed at index 0 even though it is the lowest element in the list.

It might be this inaccuracy which causes the null pointer problem at the end of the list. I would consider putting the statement `front = front.next;` *after* the inner for loop and *before* the `swap(a, lowestIndex);` statement. This will prevent the possible error in the first iteration and might solve your problem.

Comment: I think this fixed it for me. I messed with a few other parts but now it works. Thanks!

Comment: What can I do to make it sort a list of 10000 numbers faster?

Comment: You should look into other sorting algorithms. Selection sort is not a very efficient sorting algorithm under most circumstances. I suggest reading up on some different sorting algorithms on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms) and compare their complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're trying to access the content of a null element. When you're on the last element, your "current" will null when you set it to next.

I think I'm a little too tired to provide a fix for it, but you should be able to compare your old (working) code to it and spot the fix.

Comment: yes, but I cant find where it could be setting it's content to null. My swap method works perfectly, I just tested it. and I handle for the last element's next being null with this line right?         if(current.next == null)break;

Comment: @glowcoder: actually it seems the null pointer exception occurs _before_ the end of the list. The algorithm is sorting a list of 1000 elements and it throws a null pointer at element 99.

Comment: @Cody are you sure you want current = front.next instead of current = front?  Aside from that, why not just set a breakpoint and watch whats going on after 98?

Comment: Sorry, that should be 100 not 1000. I am very tired.
@Pete, the code is just wierd, I am trying to set pointers to the object that A represents(front) and the next one(current, or front.next).

Comment: @Cody It just looks like an off by one error since the problem occurs just before the last element is reached.  If it is an off by one, I don't think there is enough info in your question for us to be able to tell if thats the problem.  Setting a breakpoint and debugging will surely show where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I think Im moving in the right direction now. Ive never used debugging very thoroughly up until now but its helping. Thanks pete.